# angular.js ... $scope function returns same result on different positions

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scope

When i use my $scope function on different positions, it returns the same result.

Javascript:

```
$scope.isActive = function(d) {
    var res = false;

    if(typeof d.route !== 'undefined') {
        res = d.route === $location.path();
    } else if(typeof d.path !== 'undefined') {
        var regexp = new RegExp('^' + d.path.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&") + '.*', 'g');
        res = $location.path().match(regexp);
    }

    return res;
};
```

HTML-Source:

```
<li class="dropdown" ng-class="{active: isActive({path: '/setup'})}">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-3x"></i><br/>
        Einstellungen <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive({route: '/setup/systemkonfiguration'})}">
            <a href="#/setup/systemkonfiguration">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-hand-o-up fa-lg"></i> 
                    Aktuelle Systemkonfiguration</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Stammdaten</li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive({route: '/setup/werkzeuge'})}">
            <a href="#/setup/werkzeuge">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sitemap fa-lg"></i> 
                    Werkzeuge</a>
        </li>
```

The problem, the function **isActive** returns TRUE at all! All items under "Einstellungen" get the active class.

But, why?

Comment: which is expected. All `isActive` calls under "Einstellungen" has `route` defined.

Comment: @dmahapatro: In the example above you see two different routes (1. Aktuelle Systemkonfiguration, 2. Werkzeuge). It seems that the first call with route: returns his result to all other calls too.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `console.log(d.route, $location.path, res);` statement just before your return to verify those values?

Comment: Yes. console.log show the correct results. The route "/setup/systemkonfiguration" returns true, others false.